# Jquery json parsing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
this is my json:

{
"box 1": [{
    "difficulty_grade": "5a+"
}, {
    "gym": "New_gym"
}, {
    "route_author": "some author"
},]}
```

[image]

This is my code:  variable `groups` contain json which showed on image

```
for (var k in groups){
$p("#panel").append('<div class="flip_sector">' + k + '<span style="float:right;margin-right:7px" id="fav_m"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><div class="sect_n"></div></div>');
for (var i = 0; i<groups[k].length;i++){
$p("<span>"+groups[k][i]['route_author']+" | "+groups[k][i]['route_author']+"</span>").insertAfter(".flip_sector");
```

Variable groups in this json on image.

```
console.log(groups[k][i]['difficulty_grade']);
}
}
```

I need to create a slidetoogle with header box 1, box2, ... , and body whick contain data from objects.

This is my output:

[image]

In this output show only first object from `box 1`. Can You help my?

Comment: What is your required output? On a side note, if you format your raw `json` and update your question, it will increase your readability. trying jsonlint website for formatting..

Comment: I add json and update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use second for incorrectly.

```
for (var k in groups){
  for (var i in groups[k]){
    console.log(groups[k][i]['difficulty_grade']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix my problem. This is fixed code.

```
var count = 0;
    for (var k in groups){

$p(".loader_sector").append('<div class="flip_sector" id="sector_id_'+count+'"><div class="header" style="padding: 6px;margin-bottom:4px;margin-left: -10px;padding-left: 13px;">' + k + '<span style="float:right;margin-right:7px" id="fav_m"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></div><div id = "container_id_'+count+'" class="container_class" style="display:none"></div></div>');
console.log(groups[k]);

for (var i = 0; i< groups[k].length; i++) {
console.log(groups[k][i]['difficulty_grade']);
$p("#container_id_"+count+"").append("<div class='pan_sect' data-count='"+count+"'><div style='margin-bottom:-33px'><img style='height:46px!important;border-radius:100%' src='/dev/application/modules/User/externals/images/nophoto_user_thumb_profile.png'/><div style ='position:relative;bottom:46px;left:64px;color:#009c89'>"+ groups[k][i]['route_author'] +"</div>" + "<span style = 'font-size:10px;color:grey;position:relative;left:64px;bottom:46px'>" + groups[k][i]['route_name'] + "| Grade: " + groups[k][i]['difficulty_grade'] + "| Box4" + "</span></div><hr style='width:96%'></div>");
}count++;

}
```

Problem: When I append here:

```
$p("#container_id_"+count+"").append("<div class='pan_sect' data-count='"+count+"'><div style='margin-bottom:-33px'><img style='height:46px!important;border-radius:100%' src='/dev/application/modules/User/externals/images/nophoto_user_thumb_profile.png'/><div style ='position:relative;bottom:46px;left:64px;color:#009c89'>"+ groups[k][i]['route_author'] +"</div>" + "<span style = 'font-size:10px;color:grey;position:relative;left:64px;bottom:46px'>" + groups[k][i]['route_name'] + "| Grade: " + groups[k][i]['difficulty_grade'] + "| Box4" + "</span></div><hr style='width:96%'></div>");
```

earlier I add new div with the same class. I create difficult id's using variable `count` and add it to  `$p("#container_id_"+count+"")`